# Dot(.) not working on PrimeFaces Extensions inputNumber

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions

I'm using PrimeFaces Extensions component InputNumber

```
<pe:inputNumber id="itemOPGPriceFactor" value="#{itemOPG.priceFactor}" decimalPlaces="6" decimalSeparator="," thousandSeparator="." />
```

When using the numeric keypad to type it is working perfectly: don't matter if I type "." or "," the correct decimal separator "," will be put on the inputNumber.

But when using the "." outside of numeric keypad, the component is not accepting it and nothing is put on the inputNumber. The comma works fine.

Some idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems that the thousand separator is just for rendering and not for the input case.

You can implement a custom converter or validator for this field or some javascript